# Can I deduce $f(\textrm{Ker}(g))=g(\textrm{Ker}(f))=0$ from this data?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $A, B$ two $R$-algebras. Consider $f, g: A\longrightarrow B$, $h:B\longrightarrow A$ and $\imath:A\longrightarrow A$ morphisms of $R$-algebras satisfying:

- $A=\textrm{Ker}(f)\oplus \textrm{Im}(h)=\textrm{Ker}(g)\oplus \textrm{Im}(h)$;
- $f\circ h=g\circ h=\textrm{Id}_B$;
- $f\imath =g$;
- $g\imath =f$;
- $\imath^2=\textrm{id}_A$.

Can I deduce from this $f(\textrm{Ker}(g))=g(\textrm{Ker}(f))=0$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$kerf=ker(g\tau)=\tau^{-1}(kerg)=\tau(kerg)$ so

$g(kerf)=g\tau(kerg)=f(kerg)$,

but we have not necessarily equal to
zero in the category of $R$-module, here is an example against:

$A=\Bbb{R}^3$ , $B=\Bbb{R}^2$, 
Taking the matrices of different operators in the canonical basis
as follows: $\tau=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)$, $h=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1  \\
1& 0
\end{array}
\right)$,

$f=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$ and
$g=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$.

Then  $kerf=\{x(1,-1,-1),\;x\in\Bbb{R}\}$ ,
$kerg=\{x(1,1,1),\;x\in\Bbb{R}\}$ and
$Imh=\{x(0,1,0)+y(0,0,1),\;x,y\in\Bbb{R}\}$

so all the hypotheses are satisfied  but
$g(kerf)=f(kerg)=\{t(1,1),\;t\in\Bbb{R}\}$